# GKE resourcequota INCORRECTLY shows pod limit reached and prevents new pod creation

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I can't create new pods in my default namespace in GKE. I checked the error on deployments and replicasets using `kubectl -n default get replicaset xxxx` --> The error is:

```sh
  Warning  FailedCreate  6m54s replicaset-controller  Error creating: pods "dummy-deployment-54b6f555b7-ms5sb" is forbidden: exceeded quota: gke-resource-quotas, requested: pods=1, used: pods=5k, limited: pods=5k
```

So I ran this command *`kubectl get resourcequota gke-resource-quotas -o yaml -n default`* to look at what's going on with *gke-resource-quotas*

I get this result:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-02-04T13:06:27Z"
  name: gke-resource-quotas
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "109072XXXX"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/resourcequotas/gke-resource-quotas
  uid: 2727d85b-474f-11ea-a2f2-XXXXXXXXXX
spec:
  hard:
    count/ingresses.extensions: 5k
    count/jobs.batch: 10k
    pods: 5k
    services: "1500"
status:
  hard:
    count/ingresses.extensions: 5k
    count/jobs.batch: 10k
    pods: 5k
    services: "1500"
  used:
    count/ingresses.extensions: "7"
    count/jobs.batch: "4540"
    pods: 5k
    services: "20"
```

But I checked using *`kubectl -n default get pods | wc -l`* I do not have 5k pods running.

This is preventing me from creating new pods in my *default* namespace in GKE.

This seems like an error on part of GKE/K8s. Does anyone know how I can resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It totally looks like a GKE issue with their pre-built quotas. You might have at one point hit the *5k* limit perhaps not being updated for terminated pods and it thinks it has reached the limit.

[Someone else found a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61656760/2989261) so I would just try that for now:

```sh
kubectl delete resourcequota gke-resource-quotas -n default
```

If you are running at that scale and this is an important recurring issue I would strongly recommend hitting [GKE/GCP support](https://cloud.google.com/support). Or seek alternatives like running outside of GKE.

✌️

Comment: Thank you. This seemed to resolve the issue. I applied it to other namespaces as well. We have multiple cronjobs running every 30 minutes. For some reason, their pods don't get auto deleted - which contributed to the 5k number probably.